# Sublime Text 3 в качестве дефолтного редактора в ubuntu mate 14.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3

Sublime Text 3 никак не хочет становиться текстовым редактором по-умолчанию в ubuntu mate 14.04.2
Что сделано:

1. Установлен sublime-text 3 с офф сайта и с репозитория ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
2. В /usr/share/applications/defaults.list заменены все gedit на sublime_text
3. Проверил на существование /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop

Надоело уже разбираться, файлы всегда открываются то в gedit, то в bluma, то libre office (по мере удаления конкурентов :) )
Когда конкуренты были удалены, все равно не открываются файлы в sublime под предлогом "Нет установленного приложения для файлов типа сценарий PHP
Найти подходящее приложение для открытия этого файла?"

Если открывать через пункт "Открыть в другой программе", то открывается просто пустой sublime-text-3

В свойствах файла при этом указана программа sublime-text-3 как редактор по-умолчанию.

Печаль моя не имеет предела.
При установке на виртуальную машину ubuntu mate ведет себя точно так же, из-за чего делаю выводы: либо делаю что-то неверно, либо что-то с дистрибутивом (что вряд ли).

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Ubuntu Tweak есть графический редактор ассоциаций. Можно подключить официальный `PPA`

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

обновить индексы

```
sudo aptitude update
```

и собственно поставить:

```
sudo aptitude -y install ubuntu-tweak
```